# How can i calculate the quotients of a Fibonacci series in R

Tags: r, for-loop, math, fibonacci

I want to calculate the quotients of a Fibonacci series, such that:

[image]

I have created a function to calculate the Fbonacci series, and is ok, but i'm having troubles calculating the quotients. This is my function:

```
fibonacci <- function(n){
  numbers <- numeric(n)
  numbers[1] <- 1
  numbers[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:n)  
    numbers[i] <- numbers[i-1]+numbers[i-2]
  return(numbers)
}
```

This will calculate the Fibonacci sequence. This is what i have tried to calculate the quotients:

```
fibonacci_q <- function(n){
  numbers <- numeric(n)
  numbers[1] <- 1
  numbers[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:n)  
    numbers[i] <- numbers[i-1]+numbers[i-2]
  return(numbers/numbers[i-1])
}
```

This not working properly, it returns really small numbers, and i'm not getting the same results displayed in the table above. Can someone explain me what i'm i doing wrong and how to fix it please?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are dividing all numbers with `n-1`th number. Your function is giving you values

```
fibonacci_q(10)
#[1] 0.0294 0.0294 0.0588 0.0882 0.1471 0.2353 0.3824 0.6176 1.0000 1.6176
```

which is equal to

```
fibonacci(10)/34
#[1] 0.0294 0.0294 0.0588 0.0882 0.1471 0.2353 0.3824 0.6176 1.0000 1.6176
```

why 34? because it is 9th number in `fibonacci(10)` sequence (which is `n-1`th number).

You need to change the function to

```
fibonacci_q <- function(n){
   numbers <- numeric(n)
   numbers[1] <- 1
   numbers[2] <- 1
   for (i in 3:n)  
     numbers[i] <- numbers[i-1]+numbers[i-2]
  return(c(NA, numbers[-1]/numbers[-length(numbers)]))
}

fibonacci_q(10)
# [1]   NA 1.00 2.00 1.50 1.67 1.60 1.62 1.62 1.62 1.62
```

which is now equal to

```
c(NA, fibonacci(10)[-1]/fibonacci(10)[-10])
#[1]   NA 1.00 2.00 1.50 1.67 1.60 1.62 1.62 1.62 1.62
```

Comment: damn, i was stuck in that. So basically, you remove the first element from the vector of numbers. But later, what is the `numbers[-length(numbers)` doing??

Comment: @Miguel2488 it removes the last number from the vector of numbers. So basically, 2nd number gets divided by 1st, 3rd by 2nd and nth number by n-1 th number.

Comment: ahh so this equivalent to `numbers[i-1]`??

Comment: nope. Check `a <- 1:10;n <- 10;`. Now see the difference between `a[n-1]` and `a[-n]`.

Comment: aahh i see whats happening, i was substracting 1 to each element in the vector but the way to do was to just remove the last element so the numbers would be divided by the previous number at each time, is that?

Comment: Thank you very much for yor help!! I understood it well now